# bignum too big to convert into `long' rails admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rails-admin

I am trying to search records in rails admin panel by entering a value of 569785067261691692240000 in the filter text field. I get a error "bignum too big to convert into `long'".

Search works fine if the text in the filter text field is alphanumeric but doesn't work if the text is numeric.

Can't understand what the problem is.

I am using 0.6.3 version of rails admin gem.

Comment: What's the schema definition for your table? The admin tool might be expecting 32-bit unsigned.

Comment: Rails admin panel has a search field in which only values can be given (all types). It doesn't ask for fields on which search has to be performed. It automatically searches on all documents of a mongo collection. 

ID field is BSON type field in the defined mongo table, which can be either numeric or alphanumeric. 

Search works fine for alphanumeric values but doesn't work for numeric values.

Comment: Should tag this `mongodb` if that's applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Your field might be defined as an integer/long field, which is limited to `2^32` or `2^64`. Make it a string if you want to be able to enter such a long number.

Comment: Id is not a interger/long field. I am using mongoid gem to generate id for a collection. This gem generates a unique string field (4bytes timestamp+3 bytes machine id+3 bytes process id+4 bytes for counter) for id. Issue is when a numeric id is generated and then I try to search with this id in rails admin panel. Rails admin panel doesn't ask for search field types, it only takes search values and searches the complete collection.

Comment: I see...Rails Admin Panel is then trying to cast your id to a long field somehow. You have two options here: either you truncate your search field to be shorter and you do a query with LIKE or you ask the Rails Admin Panel if this compatibility issue is known (there seem to have plenty of issues on their github page as well)